# Generic Type usage

Tags: c#, generics

Could someone confirm whether my below approach is right or has a better alternative:

```
// An interface
IAnimal
{
    pubilc void Hunt();
}

// An abstract class
Animal<T> : IAnimal
{
    public void Hunt()
    {
        UseWeapon(T);
    }

    protected abstract T GetWeapon();
    protected abstract void UseWeapon(T weapon);
}
```

So that I could have implementations like:

```
Tiger : Animal<Claw>
Hyena : Animal<Teeth>
Eagle : Animal<Beak>
```

For eg:

```
Tiger : Animal<Claw>
{
    protected override void UseWeapon(Claw claw)
    {
        // logic here
    }

    protected override void GetWeapon()
    {
        // logic here to populate props & return Claw();
    }
}
```

And then I could call:

```
IAnimal animal = GetRandomAnimal(); // OR GetTiger();
animal.Hunt()
```

Comment: What if you have to implement `Bear` which uses `Claws` as well as `Teeth` as a weapon?

Comment: This code does not work. `public void Hunt() {  UseWeapon(T);   }`

Comment: Yeah, I would agree with @DmitryBychenko, it seems to limit the available options per animal rather

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd At least it means it doesn't have to go to Code Review :)

Comment: I think you can completly get rid of generics and make all the weapons derive from the sane base/interface weapon. Then for every animal assign it's type of weapon.

Comment: I agree @meJustAndrew. Simply add a list of weapons to your abstract base-class and let all elements derive from a common `IWeapon`-interface. Apart from this I can´t see any problems on your code, it should work. Have you tried *if* it does what it is supposed to do??

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use this approach that works easily with DI:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    pubilc void Hunt();
}

interface IWeapon
{
}

Animal : IAnimal
{
    IWeapon _weapon;

    public void Animal(IWeapon weapon)
    {
       _weapon = weapon;
    }

    public void Hunt()
    {
        UseWeapon(_weapon);
    }

    protected abstract void UseWeapon(IWeapon weapon);
}
```

If you need multiple weapons, then you just inject `IEnumerable<IWeapon>` in the constructor and change the logic appropriately.